# search for images in a .xml file and extract and create them (dummys)

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Can someone help me out please?

```
sls '\d*\S*.jpg' .\test.xml -ca).matches | select -exp value
```

Comment: You're missing an opening `(`

Comment: I guess you mean: (sls '\d*\S*.jpg' .\TVA_000150_20160114194134.xml -ca).matches | select -exp value but even when i do that it gives me an exception

Comment: Then tell/show us what exception you're getting. Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center

Comment: Exception i'm getting is as following: The term 'sls' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spellin
g of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:5
+ (sls <<<<  '\d*\S*.jpg' .\test.xml -ca).matches | select -exp value
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (sls:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Ahh, is this PowerShell 2.0? `Select-String` (which `sls` is an alias for) is not available prior to 3.0

Comment: You are my hero, problem solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As [Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38633300/powershell-or-bat-file-to-search-for-images-in-a-xml-file-and-extract-and-creat#comment64651535_38633300) pointed out in the comments, [`Select-String`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx) is not available prior to PowerShell v3. It can be replaced with a `Where-Object` filter:

```
Get-Content 'C:\path\to\file.txt' | Where-Object { $_ -match 'expression' }
```